# "the last time you saw him" vs "for the last time"?

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between the following sentences:

> 1 When was the last time you saw him.

> 2 When did you see him for the last time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For the last time* implies some finality. Typically it implies you will never see him again. It could also mean you saw him several times, and the person is asking about the last of those encounters, with the emphasis on how that was the last of those meetings, and not about the fact that you haven't seen him since then.

*The last time you saw him* is neutral and doesn't imply any deeper meaning, so that's generally what you'd want to say.